# Let $F$ be the splitting field of $\psi_{12}(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $\psi_{12}$ the cyclotomic polynomial.

Tags: galois-theory

So, we know that $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}) = \{\operatorname{id}, \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 , \sigma_3 \}$, with $\sigma_1 (\xi) = \xi^5$, $\sigma_2 (\xi) = \xi^7$, $\sigma_3 (\xi) = \xi^{11}$. I want to prove that $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_i, i=1,2,3.$ My point is:

$$\sigma_1^2(\xi)= \sigma_1 (\sigma_1(\xi)) = \sigma_1 (\xi^5) = \xi^{25} = \xi$$

and that's not $\sigma_1$. What am I doing wrong? Can you guys help me?

Thanks =]

Comment: Your correct displayed formula needs just one more equality: “$=\text{id}(\xi)$”. And then you’ve proved that $\sigma_1^2=\text{id}$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to prove $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_i$ as this can only happen in a group if $\sigma_i$ is the identity element. You want to prove $\sigma_i^2 = \operatorname{id}$ which you have done for $i = 1$. Then you will be able to conclude that $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the Klein four group.